# Error in x[[jj]] <- v : attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex

Tags: r

I have been having trouble with this code, which the aim is to run regressions for different blocks, each of them with 161 data points. It seems that it is not taking into account all the values of the number_of_regressions, which is a sequence of number from 0 to 86 by 1.

Error: Error in x[[jj]] <- v : 
  attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex

```
n <- 161

 # Creates a sequence of numbers to replace i in the for loop 

    number_of_regressions <- c(0:86) # (from 0 to 86)


    # Regression

    for(i in number_of_regressions) {
      Regression <- lm(y ~ x + z, data = Data[(1+n*i):(n*(i+1)),])
      Intercept[i] <- summary(Regression)$coefficients[1,1]
      x[i] <- summary(Regression)$coefficients[2,1]

    }
```

The aim is to run multiple regressions from the first data point to the 161th and then from 162 to 322, it means making moving blocks of 161 data points each of them.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: `r` isn't 0-indexed, so would need to use `c(1:87)`.

Comment: Yes, but I need that i takes the value of 0, and then 1,2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this, basically set up a data.frame, the first column is what you iterate through:

```
Data = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(150000),ncol=3))
colnames(Data) = c("x","y","z")

results = data.frame(n=0:86,Intercept=NA,x=NA)

n <- 161
number_of_regressions <- c(0:86) 
for(i in number_of_regressions) {
      Regression <- lm(y ~ x + z, data = Data[(1+n*i):(n*(i+1)),])
      results[results$n==i,c("Intercept","x")] = summary(Regression)$coefficients[1:2,1]
}
```